# Cursor appears as block and without typical editing abilities

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've tried over the last month or so to figure this out.

After some configuration, my cursor in VSCode started appearing as a block.  In that state, Im not able to backspace or edit any of the code.  In a saved file with code already written, I can hit the "I" key, and it changes the cursor back to the standard bar with editing capabilities.

[image]

When I start a new file, I cannot seem to get out of the bar state.  Ultra frustrating/annoying.  Any help would be SUPER appreciated!

Comment: Which extensions are enabled and what version of VSCode do you have? There is a setting `Editor: Cursor Style` which can be `block` but it only affects the appearance, may not have anything to do with being unable to edit code. There is a read-only mode where (at least in 1.39.1) trying to edit results in `Cannot edit in read-only editor` tooltip appearing; that is the mode I get into when double-clicking a file listed in 
`STAGED CHANGES` in the `Source Control` pane. I'd recommend to disable all extensions in the `Extensions` pane, see if the problem goes away and then bisect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following advice from V-R.  Disabled all extensions and then reactivated everything I needed - that did the trick! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

You may install the Vim package. Disabling or uninstalling it may solve the problem.

Comment: Wow that was it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the key <kbd>i</kbd>. I was having the same issues but every time I have this issue, pressing the <kbd>i</kbd> key helped and enabled normal editing with a normal cursor.

Comment: The OP has said, in their question: *I can hit the "I" key, and it changes the cursor back...*

Answer (score 1):

I recently found out that, this happens when you press **insert** button. Press it again and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally toggled "Vim mode" in Visual Studio Code. Just go to the command palette and search for `Vim: Toggle Vim Mode` and click it once.
Happened with me sometime back.